# In web2py, when I try to append a pandas series to a new data frame, I don't see any data in the dataframe. What could be the reason?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web2py, recommendation-engine

Here's two functions, one called
`get_recommendations(watched_movies)`
for getting movie recommendations, where `watched_movies` is a dictionary

```
def get_recommendations(watched_movies):

    print(watched_movies)
    similar_movies = pd.DataFrame()

    for movie_id,movie in watched_movies.items():
        similar_movies = similar_movies.append(get_similar_movies(movie["title"],movie["rating"]),ignore_index=True)
    
    all_recommend = similar_movies.sum().sort_values(ascending=False)

    recommended_movies = []
    for movie,score in all_recommend.iteritems():
        if not check_seen(movie,watched_movies):
            recommended_movies.append(movie)    

    if len(recommended_movies) > 100:
        recommended_movies = recommended_movies[0:100]        

    return recommended_movies
```

and another function called `get_similar_movies` which takes `movie_name` and `user_rating` as parameters

```
def get_similar_movies(movie_name,user_rating):
    try:
        similar_score = item_similarity_df[movie_name]*(user_rating-2.5)
        similar_movies = similar_score.sort_values(ascending=False)
    except:
        print("don't have movie in model")
        similar_movies = pd.Series([])
    
    #similar_movies = similar_movies.to_frame().reset_index()
   # print("similar_movies variable type : ", type(similar_movies))
    #print("similar_movies variable data : \n", similar_movies)
    return similar_movies
```

The problem is in the for loop when appending a Pandas Series to a Pandas Dataframe inside the `get_recommendations(watched_movies)`.

I don't see anything being appended and don't have a clue where the underlying problem is.

I believe that there may be something wrong with the append() function.
So please kindly provide some guidelines on how to debug this.

I tried printing the output of the `get_similar_movies(movie_name,user_rating)` function and got the output on the prompt as shown in this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX9M7.png).